# clip a fixed div from a scrolling div underneath

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, clip-path

I have a fixed header that I only want to show when it is on top of a specific image.

As the user scrolls I want the the fixed header to begin to hide as the image scrolls beneath it
[image]

```
      <Header 
        position=fixed
        clip-path=url(#clip-stage.id)> Fixed Header RED
      </Header>
      <Slide
       position=absolute
      >
       <svg 
        position=absolute
       >
        <defs>
            <clipPath id=clip-stage.id}>
              <rect 
                x=0 y=0 height=100% width=100%
              />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
       </svg>
    </Slide>
```

** added pseudo css code for reference **

---

I attempted creating a clipPath around every background image which didnt work for me and believe that maybe some overflow trickery could work.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Bootstrap and build a quick navbar. You could easily code or copy and paste some JS that would hide the navbar on scroll.

The css for this would be:

```
display:none;
```

The point is Bootstrap makes all this and more very easy!

Comment: I dont want to hide on scroll, I want the text only be visible when its overlayed on its corresponding image. Thanks for helping me on this though